# load somesound.bank and play, c++ with fmod

Tags: c++, events, audio, fmod

i am trying to use fmod with a c++ project and created a soundbank.
when i try to load it, no error is shown but it wont play any sound.

here is the *soundengine.h:*

```
...
static FMOD_RESULT result;
static FMOD::Studio::System * fmodStudio;
static FMOD::Studio::Bank* masterBank;
static FMOD::Studio::EventDescription * eventDesc;
static FMOD::Studio::EventInstance * engine;
...
static void loadBank();
```

and *soundengine.cpp*

```
...
FMOD::Studio::System * SoundEngine::fmodStudio;
FMOD::Studio::Bank * SoundEngine::masterBank;
FMOD::Studio::EventDescription * SoundEngine::eventDesc;
FMOD::Studio::EventInstance * SoundEngine::engine;
...

void SoundEngine::initialise (void) 
{
result = FMOD::Studio::System::create(&fmodStudio);
if (result != FMOD_OK) possible = false; 
if (possible)result = fmodStudio->initialize(320, FMOD_STUDIO_INIT_NORMAL, FMOD_INIT_NORMAL, 0);
if (result != FMOD_OK) possible = false;
//sets initial sound volume (mute)
if (possible) channel->setVolume(0.0f);
fmodStudio->update();
}

void SoundEngine::loadBank()
{
//load master bank
if (possible)result = fmodStudio->loadBankFile("EnvironmentSound.bank", FMOD_STUDIO_LOAD_BANK_NORMAL, &masterBank);
if (result != FMOD_OK) possible = false;
result = fmodStudio->getEvent("event:/StaticSounds/Engine", &eventDesc);
result = eventDesc->createInstance(&engine);
engine->start();
fmodStudio->update();
}
```

then i simply call the *SoundEngine::loadBank();* in *main.cpp*
it runs and all but there is no sound. i placed *EnvironmentSound.bank* in the same folder of *main.cpp*, not sure about the *"event:/StaticSounds/Engine"* though. as i just followed the example of fmod *simple_event.cpp*
**Can anyone point out the mistakes i make?
if there isnt enough info please let me know.**

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to answer this, but the problem here at least for me, is that you didn't loaded the bank strings, so you can't find the events with the string "event:/StaticSounds/Engine".

```
if (possible)
    result = fmodStudio->loadBankFile("EnvironmentSound.strings.bank", FMOD_STUDIO_LOAD_BANK_NORMAL, &masterBank);
```